# How to validate List<Map> input in Mule datamapper

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have been trying to map a List into an XML with lastest Mule Datamapper (3.5.1). Problem I met is:

Given this List essentially is a resultset from DB query, so every Map inside this List has same amount of k:v pairs. And one of them is called "Contact_Name", which could be either a **String value** or an **empty String**, mapped into xml side as `<contactName>JohnDoe</contactName>`

Could someone guide me about how should I validate this "Contact_name" and if it's an empty string then make sure in the xml side I won't have an empty node like `<contactName/>` ?

The xpath towards java map seems tricky and there is lack of such documentations from Mule.

edit: could anyone advise if rules or mapping conditions help? Especially the `condition` in the mapping structure editor, I couldnt find any doc explaining what syntax should I use there.

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the 'script' view in the data mapper viewer, you can use expressions to check if the input argument is null or empty. Fore example:

```
if(input.Contact_Name != null) output.contactname = input.Contact_Name
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I also wonder if rules or mapping conditions could help here? I ve updated the op